# Replace every other occurence with different replacements

Tags: php

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
$post = "Test $asd$ lol test asd $test$";
```

I want it to become:

```
$post = "Test [bb]asd[/bb] lol test asd [bb]test[/bb]";
```

Which is the easiest/best way to accomplish this? Note that the number of $ occurrences differs from time to time. The basic idea is to replace every other occurrence with [b] respectively [/bb].

I hope you understand.

Comment: You are using a `$` sign in a `double quoted "` text block.  PHP will assume these to be variable names and is likely to error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
<?php
$str  = $post = 'Test $asd$ lol test asd $test$';
echo preg_replace('/\$(\w+)\$/','[bb]$1[/bb]',$str);
?>
```

Output :

```
Test [bb]asd[/bb] lol test asd [bb]test[/bb]
```

Comment: Be sure to make that a lazy match with (\w+?) or ([^$]+) - the latter is better as it can capture word-breaking input, too; ie you can match `$lol!$` (but make sure you got no other "$" in the string and use single-quoted input as @Kami notes above)